# I cannot find AWS Server IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, subdomain, registrar

Does someone knows where is the AWS server IP on AWS's console?

I deployed a beanstalk application and I need to point this one to an external subdomain

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy an Elastic Beanstalk application, you are given a public endpoint of the form `https://myapp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`, which is aliased in Amazon Route 53 to your Beanstalk application's load balancer. For more, see [Web Server Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-webserver.html).

If you own a domain name, you can use Route 53 to resolve it to your Beanstalk application. See [Your Elastic Beanstalk environment's Domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html).